# yup validate names that are composed as `someName${index}`

Tags: react-native, schema, react-hook-form, yup

I have a logic that the user can add fields.

This fields are composed as names:

```
const lopeName = `lope${index}`
const lopeQnt = `qnt${index}`
```

Which is used as the following:

```
 {quantidadeDeLotes.map((lote, index) => {
        const lopeName = `lope${index}`
        const lopeQnt = `qnt${index}`
        return (
          <View
            style={{ flexDirection: 'row', marginTop: spacing.s }}
            key={index}
          >
            <TextInput
              control={control}
              type={'default'}
              name={lopeName}
              placeholder="Lote"
              viewStyle={{ flex: 0.7 }}
            />
            <View style={{ width: 20 }}></View>
            <TextInput
              control={control}
              type={'default'}
              name={lopeQnt}
              placeholder="Quantidade"
              viewStyle={{ flex: 0.3 }}
              mask={MASKS.CRM}
              keyboardType={
                Platform.OS === 'android' ? 'numeric' : 'number-pad'
              }
            />
          </View>
        )
      })}
```

I will need to validate this fields, they just need to be `required`, although I don't know how can I possibly validate them if I don't now how many indexes I will have.

The scheme:

```
const schema = yup.object({
  lopeName: yup.array().required(''),
  lopeQnt: yup.array().required('')
})

const {
    control,
    formState: { errors },
    handleSubmit,
    setValue,
    getValues,
    clearErrors,
  } = useForm<SchemaProps>({
    resolver: yupResolver(schema),
  })
```

somthign like regex:

```
const schema = yup.object({
  '/ˆlopeName\\.': yup.array().required(''),
  lopeQnt: yup.array().required('')
})
```